# html2pdf AddFont Roboto does not work

Tags: php, css, tcpdf, html2pdf, roboto

Hy there, I'm using [html2pdf v3](http://wiki.spipu.net/doku.php?id=html2pdf:en:v3:Accueil) to create a PDF.
That works pretty good. But now I wanted to use Google Fonts inside the PDF. So I downloaded `Roboto-Regular.ttf` and renamed it to `roboto.ttf`. Then I converted it to .php and .z (Encoding: cp1252): http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/index.php

Then I copied those two files inside the "fonts" folder and included the font:

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'de', true, 'UTF-8', array(30,18,30,18));
$html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$html2pdf->AddFont('roboto', 'normal', 'roboto.php');
$html2pdf->writeHTML($css.$content);
$html2pdf->Output($path.$pdf_name, 'F');
```

Unfortunately the Roboto Text has some pretty weird widths:

**HTML:**

```
<p>This is written with default Font Family</p>
<p style="font-family:roboto">This is written with Roboto</p>
```

**Output:**

[image]

The same happens when I set Roboto as default font `$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('roboto');`

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: it might need to be installed on the server? i know in wkhtmltopdf needs the font to be installed on the server for it to work.

Comment: I used now a different encoder: http://fonts.snm-portal.com
Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I used now a different encoder: [fonts.snm-portal.com](http://fonts.snm-portal.com) Now it works.

Comment: link is now dead

Comment: however, new link I tested it works for "Roboto" font is: http://fonts.palettize.me, but there is no glyphs which seems to be the common problem.